# size of an array

Tags: php, arrays

is there a way of finding the sizeof an array without using `sizeof($array)` and / or `count($array)`?

Comment: what is the restriction that u can not use both function??

Comment: Why do you want any other if there are already 2 functions.? Are you having any problem with this?

Comment: @diEcho. I second that question

Comment: Up-voted the answers to counter whoever decided to down-vote valid answers to a bad question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know the number of items in an array, you have two solutions :

- Using the `count()` function -- that's the best idea
- Looping over all items, incrementing a counter -- that's a bad idea.

For an example using the second idea :

```
$num = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $num++;
}

echo "Num of items : $num";
```

But, again : bad idea !

**Edit :** just for fun, here's another example of looping over the array, but, this time, using [**`array_map()`**][1] and an anonymous function *(requires PHP >= 5.3)* :

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$count = 0;

array_map(function ($item) use (& $count) {
    $count++;
}, $array);

echo "Num of items : $count";
```

Here, too, bad idea -- even if fun ^^

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use `foreach` and manually count the number of elements in the array, but I don't see why you would want to since this will provide no advantage over using either the `sizeof` or `count` functions.

Comment: there is no particular reason. I just wanted to do it manually at once. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Even though there is no point doing a foreach or anything else for that matter... what about array_reduce:

```
array_reduce($array, function($count, $element) {
    return $count + 1;
}, 0);
```

Just for something different :D

Comment: +1 I always like the "just for something different" answers, especially when they're clever. PHP >= 5.3 of course